How to modularize dependent unit tests in Python
Here is a hypothetical composite unit test. It calls two algorithms, checks some properties of the results independently, and then compares them to each other.
class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
   def test_composite(self):
      # Test 1. Testing first algorithm
      result1 = algorthm1()
      assert len(result1) == 5, "Algorithm 1 failed"

      # Test 2. Testing second algorithm
      result2 = algorthm2()
      assert len(result2) == 5, "Algorithm 2 failed"

      # Test 3. Testing that algorithms are consistent
      assert result1 == result2, "Algorithm results are inconsistent"

It would be convenient if the first and the second test could be run independently of each other, and the last test, that depends on both of them, would only run if the other two have passed. If only one of the algorithms failed, it would be convenient to know that the second one passed. It would also be convenient if I only had to compute the results of each algorithm once.
Is there an intended pythonic way to do such refactoring, and, if yes, what are my options?
NOTE: One solution I am aware of would be to calculate both results in the __init__(), and then only test them in the test functions. However, since the algorithms can crash, it would make sense that the algorithm computations are done in their own tests, so it is clear which one crashed.

From one perspective, the existence of this test suggests that algorithm1 and algorithm2 are redundant, and one should replace the other. Why have two functions that should always do the same thing?

I can't come up with a use case where test3 is not a bad practice. To test algorithm1 and algorithm2, you should test them both against the expected result (independently) not against each other. Can you share more details on why you need 2 algorithms that produce the same result and why they only need to be consistent between each other and not a specific result?

(1) We maintain two libraries that do the same thing as a safety measue. Both are open-source projects not developed by us. For both, there have been years where project maintainance was next to non-existent. In case there is a bug in one of them or it gets derailed too much, we can easily switch to the other.
(2) Indeed, we do also test against ground truth, which is always better. It is currently prefered to keep the ground truth file relatively small, so this is a compromise (there would be tens of thousands of ground truth examples for full coverage).

I appreciate the deep analysis of the purposes of our code. It helps me and others be better programmers in the future. However, I would also appreciate if you could focus your attention on the queston. Is this kind of testing at all envisioned by python unit testing framework? If the answer is a hard no, please provide evidence, and I will reconsider our methodology. If yes, please tell me how to do it.

@chepner I'm actually quite surprised by your question. In my experience, this is quite common. Consider different sorting algorithms or different linear solvers. They exist because some are faster/slower in different specific contexts. But still, they "do the same thing", in the sense that they are functions that take the same input and produce the same output (up to floating point precision, but that is another story).

They do the same thing, but you don't test if insertion sort works by seeing if it produces the same output as selection sort; you test it by seeing if it produces sorted output.

Ok, so you agree that having multiple algorithms doing the same thing makes sense. I indeed accept that testing against ground truth is the best thing, in case ground truth has full coverage, which is a goal worth pursuing. But comparing two methods to each other is certainly better than nothing as an intermediate solution, in case full coverage ground truth takes a long time to establish.

If algorithm1 and algorithm2 really are semantically identical, than running tests on each with shared inputs and expected outputs implies that result1 == result2 should be true by transitivity of ==. An explicit test is basically a test of your other tests, not a unit test for either algorithm.

I'm sorry, I am not 100% sure I understand your comment, please correct me if I musunderstood it. Tests 1 and 2 are there to check whether each algorithm runs without crashing, and to test whether the format of the output is as expected. The 3rd test is there to check whether the actual content of the output matches. So the results of the 3rd test are not implied by the results of the first two. Again, if I had ground truth for every test case, I would not need the 3rd test, but that is not the case.
